# If value is in multidimensional array

Tags: jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm having a problem with my `$.getJSON` function, first I store all my friends in a array like this:

```
var friends = [];
friends.push({
    user: {
        username: value.username,
        uuid: value.uuid,
        accepted: value.accepted,
        sent: value.sent
    }
});
```

This get's it's data from a `$.getJSON` function and works fine.

Then I have a search function, where I search for a username from my database like this:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.search', function() {
        $.getJSON('url?username='+$(this).val(), function(data){
            $.each(data, function(index, value){
                friends.filter(function (friend) {
                    if(friend.user.username == value.username){
                       //Append custom
                    } else {
                        //append data from JSON
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

If friends array have a object, this works fine. But if it's empty, nothing happends, it does not append anything.

What's wrong here? Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `filter` to return the matching items in the array by evaluating whether your case is `true`.

```
var matches = friends.filter(function (friend) {
    return friend.user.username == value.username
});
if (matches.length > 0) {
    //you had a match in the friends array
    console.log(matches[0]);
} else {
    //you didn't have a match in the friends array
}
```

Here is a [fiddle demonstrating the idea](https://jsfiddle.net/d8qrnnwy/1/)